# updating mysql table value after click

Tags: php

I have html table that is getting some values from mysql. I need to update a specific row in that table by the user id.

Here is admin.php Code

```
    if (isset($_POST['btnApprove'])) {
         update_approve_user();
    }

<form action="./admin.php" method="post">
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
     <tr>
       <th>user id</th>
       <th>Approved?</th>
       <th></th>
     </tr>
     <?php get_users_func(); ?>
   </table>
</form>
```

My PHP code

```
<?php

function get_users_func() {

    $query = "SELECT user_id, approved FROM users";
    $run = mysql_query($query);
    if ($run = mysql_query($query)) {
        while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
          echo '<tr>
                    <td name="uId">' . $query['user_id'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $query['approved'] . '</td>
                    <td> <input type="submit" name="btnApprove" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Approve" /> </td>
                </tr>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Problem with function';
    }
}

function update_approve_user(){
    $user_id = $_POST['uId'];

    $query = "UPDATE users SET approved = 0 WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}'";
    if ($run = mysql_query($query)) {
        echo "Approved successfully !!";
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        echo "Problem with query";
        return FALSE;
    }
}
?>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Undefined index: uId.
```

How can I pass this post method to the variable ?

Comment: <td name="uId"> this is the uId variable,and how can you access it from $_POST[]. Very strange attempt.. !!!
name="uID" should be given for some input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a text element with name `uId`:

You are assigning 'uId' as name to `<td>` element, but its not usefule as `<td>`s do not submit.

Change:

```
 echo '
        <tr> 
            <td name="uId">' . $query['user_id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $query['approved'] . '</td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="btnApprove" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Approve" /> </td>
            </tr>';
```

To

```
 echo '<tr> 
<td name="uId"><input type="text" name="uId" value="' . $query['user_id'] . '</td>
<td>' . $query['approved'] . '</td>
<td> <input type="submit" name="btnApprove" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Approve" /> </td>
</tr>';
```

Comment: Tried that and i see in my mysql log that it updates only the last row no matter what row button i clicked.

Comment: This is because you are printing the form in loop and the last value from loop is getting there in the textbox. You need to create a submit button for each element in the loop. Logically, the behaviour is correct. Just modify it so that, every user id gets printed on new row.

Comment: But i do have a submit button for each row in the table, Can you give me an example ?

Comment: Do you have a form for each row?

Comment: No, as you can see i have only one form, do i need to echo a form for each row ?

Comment: So it will not load the whole page ?

Comment: So i took your advise an change the echo code to table and than to echo the form after the while statement so it will echo the form tag for each row and it worked fine ! thanks a lot.